# Modify part of the JAVA_HOME folder path using powershell

Tags: java, powershell, variables, environment

I have an application that wants the Windows `JAVA_HOME` variable not to contain spaces. 
I would like an efficient PS script to get the current folder path i.e. 
`"C:\program files\java\java.versionxxxx"`, convert only `"program files"` to `"progra~1"` and update the environment variable accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick

```
$newPath = $ENV:JAVA_HOME.replace('Program Files','Progra~1')

[System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("JAVA_HOME", "$NewPath", [System.EnvironmentVariableTarget]::Machine)
```

You need local administrator access to modify Machine environment variable. Change `::machine` into `::user` if the change is for a specific user profile

Comment: That worked. Just a heads up for others, the search and replace strings are case- sensitive, so the standard search string would be "Program Files".

Comment: Added the capitals in the answer for extra clearance.